# jenkins ,vmvare centos6.0

Tags: jenkins, ssh

[05/02/18 22:40:22] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to server2.abc.com:22.
No route to host

> ERROR: Unexpected error in launching a slave. This is probably a bug
>   in Jenkins. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection is not
>   established!  at
>   com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.getRemainingAuthMethods(Connection.java:1030)
>     at
>   com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.TrileadSSHPublicKeyAuthenticator.getRemainingAuthMethods(TrileadSSHPublicKeyAuthenticator.java:88)
>     at
>   com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.TrileadSSHPublicKeyAuthenticator.canAuthenticate(TrileadSSHPublicKeyAuthenticator.java:80)
>     at
>   com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.SSHAuthenticator.newInstance(SSHAuthenticator.java:207)
>     at
>   com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.SSHAuthenticator.newInstance(SSHAuthenticator.java:169)
>     at
>   hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.openConnection(SSHLauncher.java:1173)
>     at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:701)
>     at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:696)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [05/02/18 22:40:25] Launch
>   failed - cleaning up connection [05/02/18 22:40:25] [SSH] Connection
>   closed.

Comment: OK, but... what version is Jenkins? What OS is the master in? And the slave? I assume the master and slave are on separate machine? Is the slave on vmware centOS 6? Or just the master?

Comment: Both have same os